# What exactly is redefinition of a macro in C? What's the point, given so many restrictions on it?

Tags: c, macros, redefinition

This is the first time I ran into the "redefinition of macro" concept while reading the C book by Mike Banahan [(Section 7.3.2)](http://publications.gbdirect.co.uk/c_book/chapter7/directives.html). But from what I can gauge from the following paragraph given there, redefinition won't be of any use at all other than repeating the same thing, given the tight restrictions. Of course my understanding is wrong and the author must be having a point. So can you please explain in simple terms what exactly redefinition of a macro in C is, and what exactly can we do to redefine it after we comply with the restrictions and rules given for that. A sample code will be very helpful. Thank you.

Extracted text follows:

> The Standard allows either type of macro to be redefined at any time,
> using another # define, provided that there isn't any attempt to
> change the type of the macro and that the tokens making up both the
> original definition and the redefinition are identical in number,
> ordering, spelling and use of white space. In this context all white
> space is considered equal, so this would be correct:
>
> ```
> #define XXX abc/*comment*/def hij
> #define XXX abc def hij
> ```
>
> because comment is a form of white space. The token sequence for both cases (w-s stands for a white-space token) is:
>
> ```
> # w-s define w-s XXX w-s abc w-s def w-s hij w-s
> ```

Comment: Simple, it allows multiple headers to ship the exact same macro-definition, without including each other. Normally header include-guards prevent inclusion of the same header multiple times.

Comment: Redefinition is not a feature, it's simply to allow (for example), the same header file (containing a macro) to be included multiple times without injury.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth But what remains of any redefinition given the "identical in number, ordering, spelling and use of white space" constraints? Can you explain though some code?

Comment: @Thokchom: See Deduplicator's comment.

Comment: The use of the word `redefined` in that quote was an unfortunate choice, since you're not redefining anything.  A better choice of words would have been *"The Standard allows either type of macro to be repeated at any time, ..."* If you actually want to redefine a macro, you have to `#undef` it first.

Comment: I'm not convinced there's a 'w-s' token between the `#` and the `define`, but it doesn't materially affect the discussion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In practice, you generally do not want to redefine macros.  Most of the time it happens due to name collision (two pieces of code defining a macro with the same name that may or may not do the same thing).  The rule you cite says redefinition is allowed in the case where the only difference between the two definitions is white space.  In that case, both definitions will do the same thing.  In any other case, all bets are off.

For example, a common thing to want is the maximum of two numbers.  If you write a MAX macro, one way to do it would be:

```
// ASSUME: multiple references to macro parameters do not cause problems
#define MAX(a, b) ((a) > (b) ? (a) : (b))
```

Since `MAX` is the obvious name for a macro that returns the maximum of two numbers, there is a pretty good chance that someone else might have the same idea and also define a `MAX` macro.  If they happen to define it exactly the same way you did, the compiler will accept the multiple definitions, because they do the same thing (though some compilers will still warn about it).

If someone defines `MAX` differently, the compiler will throw an error on the redefinition.  Throwing an error is a good thing.  Had the compiler always picked either the first or last definitions, the programmer would most likely not be aware that a different macro than they expected will be used.

If you need to work around multiple definitions of macros (e.g., two different 3rd party libraries choose the same name), you can use `#ifdef` to check if the macro is already defined and `#undef` to "undefine" the first definition if you would rather have the second.  Such solutions are generally fragile.  If you have a choice, avoiding name conflicts is a better solution.

Comment: The only point of the statement `do { (a) > (b) ? (a) : (b) } while(0)` would be at least one of `a` or `b` contained side-effects, and if either one has side-effects, should they really be passed to macro `MAX`?

Comment: @PascalCuoq - Sorry added the do-while out of habit without thinking.  It makes multi-statement macros work more like functions, but will break `MAX` here because it is not an rval.  The do-while won't really prevent any problems due to side effects (e.g., if the user passes `x++` for `a`, as `a` will get replaced by `x++` everywhere in the macro).